# Agent's behaviour in Multi-agent systems?

Tags: java, agent, random-access, agents-jade, multi-agent

I have request agent and several resource agents in my project. I created a agent application and when I run this application every time I got one result. thats mean I call methods step by step without going accessing these behaviours in random order. How can I implement this random behaviour in jade without using random? Because my supervisor does not like to use Random in Agent behaviour.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a deterministic multi-agent system implemented in Jade and want to make it into something unpredictable through a random behavior access. You can instantiate the agent behaviors as [DelayBehaviour](http://www.iro.umontreal.ca/~vaucher/Agents/Jade/code/ch_6/DelayBehaviour.java) with random access time. You need to change the random seed each time the system runs; otherwise, it will still be deterministic. Therefore, each time the system runs it has different random execution time for each behavior.

Look at the JADE Tutorial and Primer chapter 6 for a comprehensive documentation about it:

[DelayBehaviour](http://www.iro.umontreal.ca/~vaucher/Agents/Jade/primer6.html#6.5)

[Independent Random Generators](http://www.iro.umontreal.ca/~vaucher/Agents/Jade/primer6.html#6.6.10)

If your supervisor does not like the word Random you can call this approach "not deterministic behavior calls (NDBC)", but it is random anyway.